# Schematic for auto phase selector

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics, schematic

Can someone check the response of the schematic of auto phase selector switch, wherein MCU will read all the AC inputs of 3 phases accurately and make perfect decision for the healthy phase for the single phase load.

So, for example, if 3 phases are 220, 235 and 190 V AC, then all the 3 phases are read correctly as 220, 235 and 190 V only. Further that MCU will decide best healthy phase i.e. 220 V, based on the programming.

So kindly check analog part of the circuit if everything is correct or not? Also, components response to frequency and transient result 220 V AC 50 Hz and TINA file, kindly check whether everything is acceptable?

[image: Schematic]

[image: Response]

Comment: What are the op-amps? What powers them? What is the transformer you are using? How did you model it correctly? What will the MCU do if after selecting the "best" phase, due to loading it, it becomes the 2nd best choice? How will you mitigate against a never-ending scenario of rapidly switching phases?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.